# How to calculate values that are selected from xcode tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, core-data

i would like to make something like shopping, whenever the user selects a cell from the UITableView the price of that item will show in the total Label and when he selects another item the sum of the 2 items will show in the total label. i made a plist and store the items there. what i want to do now is how to assign the price values into the items and when the user selects a cell "item" the price will be shown. this is what i have made so far. please help me.

this is the view controller:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmku6.jpg)

```
import UIKit

class ServiceListViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tablelbl: UITableView!

    var SerArr :[ServiceOB] = []
    var ArrService: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tablelbl.delegate = self
        tablelbl.dataSource = self

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ServiceList", ofType: "plist")

        let serArray : NSArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)!
        for service in serArray {
            print(service)
            let serviceOBJ = ServiceOB()

            // i change your plist to array


            serviceOBJ.Service = service as! String
            // check now..
            SerArr.append(serviceOBJ)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return SerArr.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tablelbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServiceListCell") as! ServiceTableViewCell
        let obj = SerArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.servicelbl.text! = obj.Service

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark{

            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none        }
        else {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark

        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }

}
```

Comment: Your way to select a cell doesn't work anyway. Cells are reused and you'll get unexpected behavior when the user scrolls. You have to save the selected state in the model and set it in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: Use delegation from the cell class to add price values into total label

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged Firebase - there's not Firebase code. It's also not really clear what the issue is - if your dataSource array contains all of the item info, when a customer selected an item, just store a 'selected' flag with that object in the array and when displaying cell, if that flag it set, also show the price. Your total will be the total of all cells where that flag it set as well. Can you clarify where the difficulty is?

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegate of tablecell and call delegate method from button click in tablecell.

```
protocol tableCellDelegate {
   func callMethod()
}

class tableCell: UITableViewCell{
var delegate: tableCellDelegate?

@IBAction func selecteItem(_ sender: Any) {
  delegate?.callMethod()
}

class VC: UIViewController{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {
  let cell = .....
  cell.delegate = self
  return cell
}

func callMethod(){
  // Do some thing}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Just fetch the table cell with the original cell type that was used and keep a variable to store the value for total price:

```
@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

var price: Double = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        // You can use localisation to change the currency. But that is currently not a part of the problem statement.
        priceLabel?.text = "$\(price)"
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ServiceTableViewCell {
        // Assuming cell has a property for storing price: itemPrice
        if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            totalPrice -= cell.itemPrice
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        } else {
            totalPrice += cell.itemPrice
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: You don't need plist file for storing the selected values. But if you need it for some of the other reasons not mentioned here, you can alter the contents of the plist based on selection as well.